# Java4Kinect Retrieving 3D Joint Coordinates

Tags: java, arrays, coordinates, kinect, kinect-sdk

I've been trying to work with [J4K](http://research.dwi.ufl.edu/ufdw/j4k/index.php) to implement a feature that would allow me to drive a robot using human gestures detected by an XBox 360. Currently, I'm trying to read and print the X coordinates of the right hand, which only returns 0.0 despite being able to detect the skeleton. I've also tried replacing HAND_RIGHT with other joint constants, but to no avail.

This is my myKinect class which reads the values from the Kinect:

```
package printTest;

import edu.ufl.digitalworlds.j4k.J4KSDK;
import edu.ufl.digitalworlds.j4k.Skeleton;

public class myKinect extends J4KSDK{

    int maxSkeletons = getMaxNumberOfSkeletons();

    Skeleton skeleton;

    @Override
    public void onColorFrameEvent(byte[] arg0) {    
    }

    @Override
    public void onDepthFrameEvent(short[] arg0, byte[] arg1, float[] arg2, float[] arg3) {  
    }

    @Override
    public void onSkeletonFrameEvent(boolean[] flags, float[] positions, float[] orientations, byte[] state) {
        System.out.print(".");
        for (int i = 0; i < maxSkeletons; i++) {
            skeleton = Skeleton.getSkeleton(i, flags, positions, orientations, state, this);

            if (flags[i]){
                skeleton.get3DJoint(Skeleton.HAND_RIGHT);
            }
        }       
    }
}
```

And this is my KinectPrint class which prints out the coordinate values:

```
package printTest;

import edu.ufl.digitalworlds.j4k.J4KSDK;
import edu.ufl.digitalworlds.j4k.Skeleton;

public class KinectPrint {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        myKinect kinect = new myKinect();
        kinect.start(J4KSDK.SKELETON);
        kinect.setSeatedSkeletonTracking(true);
        System.out.println("Initializing...");

        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch(InterruptedException e) {}

        float handX;
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            handX = kinect.skeleton.get3DJointX(Skeleton.HAND_RIGHT);
            System.out.println(handX);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch(InterruptedException e) {}
        }

        kinect.stop();
        System.out.println("Completed!");
    }
}
```

Its current output is:

`Initializing...
..........................................................................................................0.0
..............................0.0
.............................0.0
............................0.0
..............................0.0
..............................0.0
..............................0.0
..............................0.0
..............................0.0
..............................0.0
..............................Completed!`

Comment: Don't link projects. Please update the question with relevant code and the issue that you're facing.

Comment: Just updated the question. Thanks!